# Running parallel and sequential tests using TestNG, Appium and Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, parallel-processing, testng, appium

I am building a test framework that should support test execution on Android, iOS and Web. Since the app is complex with many test cases (1000+) one of the requirements is to be able to execute in parallel (here should be included tests that require only single device), also having tests with parent-child behavior (chat application - the SMS send from device 'A' to device "B"). I am planning to use POM with PageFactory.

So here my initial thoughts on how to do this:

- In before suite to install the application on android/ios using CLI
- In testng.xml provide device related parameters such as udid, platform, os etc...
- In beforeMethod in BaseTest that extends all tests - to initialize driver (android, ios or web (chrome,ff...))
- AfterMethod to quit the driver (also I can have before/after methods in test level)

Pros:
easy to manage driver instance creation before each test,
manageable sequential (parent-child) test execution (in testng.xml I can specify parent and child methods)
easy manageable parallel execution.

Cons:
create an instance of the driver before each tests method will be time consuming,
if one test perform sign in, and the next test needs to send SMS, due to driver initialization in beforeMethod I need to perform sign in (code duplication) again.

Could you suggest or point to a framework that can support all mentioned requirements.
Should I use the selenium grid?

Any help is highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you can check [AppiumTestDistribution](https://github.com/AppiumTestDistribution/AppiumTestDistribution) framework and extend it for your needs.

I suggest checking [official docs](http://appium.io/docs/en/advanced-concepts/parallel-tests/) and this project is a good point to [start](https://github.com/eliasnogueira/appium-parallel-execution)

One note from myself: start driver only once in `BeforeSuite`: installing the app and appium helpers apps is time consuming; you can simply reset app state in `BeforeTest`, e.g. by starting activity

Comment: Hi, @dmle thanks for your feedback definitely I'll check the framework you mentioned. For me, the biggest challenge is to support sequentionl (device A and device B, or Web) test execution in the one test class.